# Аналог onmouseout для touch устройств

Tags: html, javascript

> onmousedown - ontouchstart
>
> onmousemove - ontouchmove
>
> onmouseup - ontouchend
>
> onmouseout - ?

Comment: я думаю, что полноценно получить onmouseout можно только если подключить мышку (это будет работать только с некоторыми планшетами) или на Galaxy Note + S-Pen. В других случаях это событие нельзя получить. А когда мышка есть, то о аналогиях не нужно задумываться.

Comment: Так я не про мышку, а про нажатие. Когда палец нажимает на элемент ABC, а потом не отпуская уходит в сторону, то по должно вызваться то, про что я спрашиваю. Т.е. onmouseout где вместо мышки палец

Comment: @danpetruk: Мне кажется не стоит связывать таким образом `mouse` и `touch` события, так как они относятся к принципиально разным устройствам, хотя и похожи.

Comment: @Deonis: если смотреть последнюю версию [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/), события `touchleave` там нет. Поэтому сложно говорить о его поддержке мобильными браузерами.

Comment: @Deonis работает, переделывайте в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [этому описанию](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#the-touchleave-event), в какой-то мере **onmouseout - touchleave**